# Bootstrap table with vertical text on column headers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for a table, I'm trying to find out how to have some, not all, column header text rotated vertically (or at 45 degree angle).

Comment: like? any example or image of your desired output?

Comment: Here's a link to an image example:  https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/45-deg.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this

```
.verticalText{
   -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   -ms-transform-origin: left top 0;
   -moz-transform-origin: left top 0;
   -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0;
   transform-origin: left top 0;
   margin-left: 40px;
   padding: 10px;
   float: left;
}
```

But the "margin-left" property is needed.